# mod_rewrite preventing from overwriting folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following mod_rewrite code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /(.*)$ index.php?action=$1
```

It shall change e.g.
http://test.com/page2 into http://test.com/index.php?action=page2

It does pretty well, but all my folders are also over-written now. How can I tell mod_rewrite  just to overwrite the root folders urls?

Comment: So you want nothing with a `/` in it to be rewritten? Only URL's like `/abc, /def-ghi` but never `/abc/def`?

Comment: And are you defining this in .htaccess or server-level/virtualhost config? (the leading `/` implies server config, not .htaccess)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski First: exactly yes. And second: just .htaccess, I have a web server so no server-level!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It doesn't affect the folders, but somehow Joomla doesn't really get it. If I call index.php?test=test by myself it's working. But if I call /test with index.php?test=$1 then it won't work (Joomla displays 404). Why?

Comment: Well you didn't mention Joomla anywhere in question.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem as mod_rewrite shall open index.php?action=$1 anyway. And this doesn't produce an 404 if I type index.php?action=whatever in. So where might the problem be?

Comment: Add R flag to make it `RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA,R]` and see if this redirects

Comment: It does. Somehow weird: var/www/vhosts/domain/folder/index.php?action=page2 // Edit: The path he redirects is perfect, but it should only open the index.php?action=page2

Comment: ok try: `RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA,R]`

Comment: It wasn't the problem. I had to set the RewriteBase. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542820/why-is-my-htaccess-file-redirecting-to-full-server-path-instead-of-relative-pat + Big Thanks!