# Apache not redirecting properly '/usr/home/username/public_html/'

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using this to redirect non-www requests to www

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It should redirect from:

```
http://example.com/intranet
```

To:

```
http://www.example.com/intranet
```

But it's redirecting to:

```
http://www.example.com//usr/home/username/public_html/intranet
```

What is happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you put it to the virtual host config or literally to `.htaccess`?

Comment: I've put it to a .htaccess file, in a subdirectory, 'intranet'.

Comment: That's curious. I have something similar to do the opposite job and it works fine: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]`

Comment: Add `RewriteBase /intranet/` if your .htaccess is inside of `/intranet/`

Comment: @Cheery: why? It will change the request string passed to the SAPI (and I `/intranet` is given as an example and a real site might have dozens of different paths)

Comment: @zerkms had the same problem recently. just do not remember what was the reason )

Comment: @Cheery, I did that, but no change.

Comment: What apache version do you run?

Comment: Yeah.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542820/why-is-my-htaccess-file-redirecting-to-full-server-path-instead-of-relative-pat Probably RewriteBase is needed if rewrite rule is in subdir. `, I did that, but no change.` no change - means it inserts to full path or it does not work? Redirected URL in this case also should include intranet.

Comment: It still display the full path. zerkms, I'll check

Comment: And, again .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778681/htaccess-rewriterule-adds-drive-path-to-url

Comment: @BernardoLima Try `RewriteBase /` as mentioned in answer, but I think it should be `RewriteBase /intranet/` and rewriterule will be, probably, `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/intranet/$1 [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've successfully used the following:

```
RewriteBase /intranet/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)          http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Do you use in the root or in subdir?

Comment: I use this in a subdir.

Comment: just wanted to mention it )

Comment: Tested the above locally and using [http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)